# SQL Remove row when other rows are subset, keep row when no subset

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data set of 300,000 rows, looking at harvested acreage in the United States. Some, but not all of my data is double counted and I am trying to remove the double counting. The data looks like this:

```
Year  | State  | Crop | Practice | Acres Harvested | Acres
-------------------------------------------------------------
2008      1      1       1         1000 or more       40
2008      1      1       1         1000 to 1999       10
2008      1      1       1         2000 to 2999       30
2008      2      1       1         1000 or more       87
2008      3      2       2         1.0 to 14.9        15
2008      3      2       2         1.0 to 4.9          5
2008      3      2       2         5.0 to 14.9        10
```

Some of the rows are subsets for other rows in the [Acres Harvested] column (rows 2 and 3 are a subset of row 1 and rows 6 and 7 are a subset of row 5). In situations where I have more detailed information for [Acres Harvested] (rows 2 and 3 provide more detail than row 1), I would like to keep the detailed information (row 2 and 3) and omit the general information (row 1). In other scenarios, I only have the general information (row 4), so that is what I will keep.

I am having trouble writing the code to omit the general information when the detailed information is present, but to keep the general information when the more detailed information does not exist.

I've been trying to write an "inner join" to join my table back with itself, but am unsure of how to omit rows when certain conditions are met. What I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM A
            GROUP BY [YEAR], [STATE], [CROP], [PRACTICE]
            HAVING COUNT (*) > 1) AS B

ON  A.Year     =    B.Year
AND A.State    =    B.State
AND A.Crop     =    B.Crop
AND A.Practice =    B.Practice
```

And now I'm stuck...

Results should look like:

```
    Year  | State  | Crop | Practice | Acres Harvested | Acres
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    2008      1      1       1         1000 to 1999       10
    2008      1      1       1         2000 to 2999       30
    2008      2      1       1         1000 or more       87
    2008      3      2       2         1.0 to 4.9          5
    2008      3      2       2         5.0 to 14.9        10
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What are your criteria for "more detailed information"?  For your example data it appears to be the records for a matched set that don't end in "or more".  Is that all of it?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've edited the sample code to show another scenario in the data. I want to have as much detail as possible for [Acres Harvested], while ensuring I'm not double counting the data.

Comment: Ok, updated my answer to reflect your new data. The overlapping number ranges make this a *lot* more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague.  This will return the result set you've specified for the input data you've specified:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.acres_harvested not like '% or more' or
      not exists (select 1
                  from a a2
                  where a2.year = a.year and a2.state = a.state and a2.crop = a.crop and
                        a2.acres_harvested like '[0-9]%to%[0-9]'
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've added some more example data and tried to clarify what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your criteria for "more detailed information" is records for a matched set that don't end in "or more" as I guessed in my comment, you can get your desired output this way.  You do the records sets with only one record and those with multiple records separately and `UNION` them instead of trying to do it with one `SELECT`.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
GROUP BY [YEAR], [STATE], [CROP], [PRACTICE]
HAVING 
    COUNT (*) = 1

UNION

SELECT A.*
FROM A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT [YEAR], [STATE], [CROP], [PRACTICE]
        FROM A
        GROUP BY [YEAR], [STATE], [CROP], [PRACTICE]
        HAVING 
            COUNT (*) > 1
    ) AS B
ON  A.[Year]     =    B.[Year]
AND A.[State]    =    B.[State]
AND A.[Crop]     =    B.[Crop]
AND A.[Practice] =    B.[Practice]
WHERE [ACRES HARVESTED] not like '%%or more'
```

If your criteria aren't what I guess just change the `WHERE` clause.

Given your updated sample data you're also going to have to check for overlapping number ranges.  This question has some options on how to do that: [Discard existing dates that are included in the result, SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46227841/discard-existing-dates-that-are-included-in-the-result-sql-server/46228615#46228615).  You'll need to split your "X to Y" values into two numeric fields as well.